# Controlling how test data is generated in QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I wrote an algorithm to find a solution to the subset sum problem in Haskell. The signature is

```
subsetSum :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> Maybe [a]
```

QuickCheck seems to be a good fit to test that. For example I here is one of the properties that I could check:

```
prop_sumEqualsS l s = case subsetSum l s of
                        Just solution -> (sum solution) == s
                        Nothing       -> True
```

The problem is that the algorithm is quite computationally intensive and running 100 tests with big input lists takes ages to run.

I tried with QuickCheck 1 and it did run quickly, but the data sets used for testing were very small. After moving to QuickCheck 2 it seems to be the opposite problem. There is [a manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html) for QC but it seems to be old (there is no date information) and I don't know how much still applies to QC2. [A Tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck) is available on the Haskell Wiki but there is not much details, just a few words on instantiating `Arbitrary`.

So I have two questions:

- What changes in QuickCheck 2 make it become so much slower than QuickCheck?
- What is the best way to control data sets creation to make them useful for a given test?

**Edit:** To be more specific, I would like to test my solution with a list size from 0 to 100, containing integers between -10000 and 10000.

Comment: Your questions seems a little vague for the context of QuickCheck; perhaps you'd be better asking a general testing question instead. There are a few problems with your current approach though: it won't check that the solution is actually a subset, or that if the function returns Nothing then there is in fact no solution.

Comment: @gatoatigrado The property was just an example. I believe checking that the solution is a subset belongs in another property. Am I wrong? I don't see an easy way to check that when Nothing is returned, there is in fact no solution, except by solving the problem again with another algorithm. This seems a bit redundant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712373/cookbook-for-converting-from-quickcheck1-to-quickcheck2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One thing that QuickCheck 2 introduced that could be a source of
inefficiency is the `shrink` function. If a property fails, then
the shrink function is called which gives candidates on smaller
test values, and they are shrunk until they cannot give a
smaller value for which the property fails. But this only
happens when properties fail.

The changes for the arbitrary instance for lists has not changed
much between [version 1](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/1.2.0.1/doc/html/src/Test-QuickCheck.html#Arbitrary)
and [version 2](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.2/doc/html/src/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#Arbitrary).
The difference is in wording, version 1 uses [`vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:vector), and version 2 uses
a list comprehension, but then `vector` is implemented with exactly such a list comprehension
of sequenced calls to arbitrary.

Both implementations used the size parameter. In QuickCheck 1, the size of 
a generated value is by
default `div n 2 + 3`, where `n` is the number of the test.
QuickCheck 2 uses another approach, where the maximum size
and the number of tests is configured. The test sizes will be distributed
in that range, growing linearly in the number of tests (see `computeSize'` in `quickCheckWithResult`).
This means, with the default setting of 100 tests and maximum size, the maximum size
from QuickCheck 1 would be `(div 100 2 + 3) = 53`, and with QuickCheck 2
it would simply be `100`.

As subset sum is NP-complete you probably have an exponential algorithm ;)
Then the difference in running time between a list of length 50 and 100
can of course be enormous. Understandably you want small lists to test with. You have two
choices: make a new data type (preferably with `newtype`) or make
a stand-alone generator and use [`forAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#v:forAll). By using `newtype` you can
also specify how values should be shrunk. This is an example implementation using the `newtype` approach:

```
newtype SmallIntList = SmallIntList [Int] deriving (Eq,Show)

instance Arbitrary SmallIntList where
  arbitrary = sized $ \s -> do
                 n <- choose (0,s `min` 50)
                 xs <- vectorOf n (choose (-10000,10000))
                 return (SmallIntList xs)
  shrink (SmallIntList xs) = map SmallIntList (shrink xs)
```

This `Arbitrary` instance does not make lists longer than 50 elements.
The elements do not use the size parameter, so they are always in
the range `[-10000,10000]`, so there is some room for improvement.
The `shrink` function simply uses the available `shrink`s for lists and
`Int`s.

To use this instance with your property, just use a `SmallIntList` as
an argument:

```
prop_sumEqualsS (SmallIntList l) s = case subsetSum l s of
                                         ...
```